# hyperlink in excel if file exists in folder

Tags: excel, if-statement, hyperlink

I want to create a hyperlink if and only if a file exists with a specific name in my folder. Otherwise I want the cell to remain blank. I have a folder with very specific file names that I want excel to search through and return the hyperlink if the name is found. I was thinking of the following code but can't get it to work:

=IF(find("8197837", foldername, "8197837"), hyperlink(folder name, 8197837), "")

Answer (score 2):

```
Function FileExists(FileName As String) As Boolean
     FileExists = (Dir(FileName) > "")
End Function
```

Create a custom function in VBA to check for a file.  You go into the visual basic editor under the developer tab, create a new module, and paste in that code.

Then in the cell you want to use do something like:

=IF(FileExists(filename),HYPERLINK(filename),"")

Comment: Can I make it so it only looks through one folder for the file?

Comment: Yes.  This function literally looks to see if the file name you provided exists or not.  If it does it returns True.  The filename you provide can be a link in another cell, or it can be a formula that joins strings together.